# Why is my mango plant having brown spots?

Tags: watering, soil, mango, browning

[image]

I really wanted to grow this plant but now seeing it like this i am getting so depressed

Comment: I think it needs water

Comment: Can you add more info in the question? I think it will be easier to help! How long have you had it? Was it okay until recently? Did anything change drastically in the environment lately? Soil and watering?